# Programmatically detect whether command can be run as module

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a function which takes a command:

```
import subprocess


def run_command(command: str):
    subprocess.run(['python', '-m', command])
```

I would like to tell whether `command` is something which can be run as `python -m <command>`.

For example:

- `doctest` would count, as I can run `python -m doctest`
- `foo` would not, as it would return `No module named foo`

Is there a way to tell, inside my function, whether `command` is a Python module which can be run?

The simplest way would just be `try-except`, but I would like to avoid that as it might mask other errors.

Comment: For `try-except`, the reason "why" doesn't really matter — the `command` can't be imported, the only thing you're trying to determine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the output of the command and check stderr to see what it returned. This code checks if the binary string "No module named" is in the stderr, which means the command wasn't found

```py
import subprocess


def run_command(command: str):
    output = subprocess.run(['python', '-m', command], capture_output=True)
    if b"No module named" in output.stderr:
      print("Command not found")
    else:
      #command was found
```